# using local var for out of order operation in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let ignore = false;    
    async function fetchProduct() {
      const response = await fetch('http://myapi/product/' + productId);
      const json = await response.json();
      if (!ignore) setProduct(json);    }

    fetchProduct();
    return () => { ignore = true };  }
, [productId]);
```

The above snippet is from https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-getderivedstatefromprops

I am not able to understand what is the purpose of the the last line `return ()=> {ignore=true}`. What is the effect of this statement, does it set the local variable true as true ? How does the `ignore` ever become true, because its set to false, and on next render it ill be again false ?

Comment: Check documentation for `useEffect`. On component unmount this return statement will be executed, which will set `ignore` to `true` to avoid memory leak. (in your case, asynchronous call to API)

Comment: Though documentation says it will execute on component unmount but from my experience this return statement will execute every time value of dependency array change. Obviously, if dependency array is empty, it will execute on component unmount.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function returned by `useEffect` is for cleanup. It's an equivalend of `componentWillUnmount` in class components.
[React hooks docs](https://pl.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#explanation-why-effects-run-on-each-update)

So overall: what happens in the hook is that the resource is fetched asynchronously. It may happen that it will finish fetching after the component is no longer on the screen. In this case it should be ignored. The cleaning runction set's `ignore` to `true` and when the asynchronous part is finally executed the `setProduct` will not be executed.

Answer (score 2):

> I am not able to understand what is the purpose of the the last line return ()=> {ignore=true}

lets assume that

1. first time component is rendered with productId=1
2. after this react runs effect first time and ajax request N1 is started
3. then productId is changed to 2
4. react render component again and run effect second time (because projectId is changed).
   Second ajax request N2 is sent
5. Second request (N2) is completed faster then first one (N1) and setProduct(product2) is called
6. Then request (N1) is complated and setProduct is called with product1

And as a result component shows product1 (but should product2).
ignore flag fixes this problem.

---

> How does the ignore ever become true, because its set to false, and on next render it ill be again false

ignore is variable inside function, so there is own instance for each execution.
`return () => { ignore = true }` makes closure to `ignore` variable for each hook execution.

so from prev example

1. render productid = 1
   useEffecte is executed first time and
   ignore**1** = false
2. render productid = 2
   useEffect run cleanup callback (from prev hook execution) and then "new" effect

   ignore**1** = true
   ignore**2** = false

So when first ajax request is completed then setProduct won't be called